GCC is not including the right OpenSSL version (multiple OpenSSL installed)
I've installed OpenSSL 3.3.1 from source with the following commands
./config '-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)' -Wl,--enable-new-dtags --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
make
make install

I then coded the following c program (test.c):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Openssl Version: %s\n", OpenSSL_version(OPENSSL_VERSION));
}

When compiling with the command
gcc test.c -o t -v -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib64/ -lssl -lcrypto

it produce the following result:
Openssl Version: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Why do I get this version? I would expect to have the 3.3.1 version. What am I doing wrong?
I also checked the include folder and the lib folder:

/usr/local/include contains the openssl folder (containing the header files)
/usr/local/lib64 contains:

libcrypto.a
libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.3
libcrypto.so.3
libssl.a
libssl.so -> libssl.so.3
libssl.so.3



To give more colour: I'm working from Ubuntu with a pre-installed OpenSSL 3.0.2 (installed in the /usr/bin folder). When using the command openssl version I obtain OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022). When using the command /usr/local/bin/openssl version I obtain OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024).
The output of gcc using the -v flag is the following:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 't' '-v' '-I' '/usr/local/include' '-L/usr/local/lib64/' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 't-'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/cc1 -quiet -v -I /usr/local/include -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu test.c -quiet -dumpdir t- -dumpbase test.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccWg0JAN.s
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 50eaa2331df977b8016186198deb2d18
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 't' '-v' '-I' '/usr/local/include' '-L/usr/local/lib64/' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 't-'
 as -v -I /usr/local/include --64 -o /tmp/ccUGX0NJ.o /tmp/ccWg0JAN.s
versione di GNU assembler 2.38 (x86_64-linux-gnu) utilizzando la versione BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 't' '-v' '-I' '/usr/local/include' '-L/usr/local/lib64/' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 't.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccRaF8GO.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o t /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/local/lib64/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. /tmp/ccUGX0NJ.o -lssl -lcrypto -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 't' '-v' '-I' '/usr/local/include' '-L/usr/local/lib64/' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 't.'


Ironically, Claude 3.5 found the solution.
Setting the RPATH explicitly solved the issue.
The successful command was:
gcc test.c -o t -v -L/usr/local/lib64/ -I/usr/local/include -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto

This is a common solution when working with custom-built libraries, especially when you have multiple versions of the same library on your system.
The -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64 option tells the linker to embed the path /usr/local/lib64 into the executable's runtime library search path. This ensures that your program will use the libraries in this directory when it runs, regardless of the system's default library paths.

Is the word Copy at the front of the command Copygcc intended?

No, thanks for the catch. Edited.
